# Python plot with 3 axes (bug in matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a python routine based on multiple_yaxis_with_spines.py (example offered in matplotlib page http://matplotlib.org/) that doesn't work properly after upgrading matplotlib beyond the version 1.1.1 (even the original is bugged). The third axe (in red) doesn't appear anymore and the correspondent data is ploted following the blue axe (left) [see image and code below].
I work currently in Windows 7 with python 2.7.3 32bits, matplotlib 1.1.1 > 
My questions are: What have changed in the matplotlib library that affected this function?
How to solve this issue and allow me to upgrade python and libraries without problems?
http://tinypic.com/r/33pfz13/5 - How data should appear

```
    def make_patch_spines_invisible(ax):
        par2.set_frame_on(True)
        par2.patch.set_visible(False)
        for sp in par2.spines.itervalues():
            sp.set_visible(False)

    def make_spine_invisible(ax, direction):
        if direction in ["right", "left"]:
            ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position(direction)
            ax.yaxis.set_label_position(direction)
        elif direction in ["top", "bottom"]:
            ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position(direction)
            ax.xaxis.set_label_position(direction)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Unknown Direction : %s" % (direction,))
        ax.spines[direction].set_visible(True)

    if 1:
        fig = plt.figure()
        host = fig.add_subplot(111)
        par1 = host.twinx() 
        par2 = host.twinx() 
        par2.spines["right"].set_position(("axes", 1.1))
        make_patch_spines_invisible(par2)
        make_spine_invisible(par2, "right")
        plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.8) 
        p1, = host.plot(t,hmf2i,'b-',label="hmf2")
        p2, = par1.plot(t,fof2i,"r-",label="foF2")
        p3, = par2.plot(t,hvirfi,'g-',label="h\'F")
        host.set_xlim(0,24) 
        #host.set_ylim(250,600)
        #par1.set_ylim(9,18)
        #par2.set_ylim(200,450)
        host.set_xlabel("Hora (UT)")
        #host.set_ylabel("hmF2 (km)")
        #par1.set_ylabel("foF2 (MHz)")
        #par2.set_ylabel("h\'F (km)") 
        host.yaxis.label.set_color(p1.get_color())
        par1.yaxis.label.set_color(p2.get_color())
        par2.yaxis.label.set_color(p3.get_color()) 
        tkw = dict(size=4, width=1.5)
        host.tick_params(axis='y',colors=p1.get_color(),**tkw)
        par1.tick_params(axis='y',colors=p2.get_color(),**tkw)
        par2.tick_params(axis='y',colors=p3.get_color(),**tkw) 
        host.tick_params(axis='x',**tkw)
        lines = [p1, p2, p3] #(comentar se não houver terceiro plot)
        host.legend(lines,[l.get_label() for l in lines],loc = 'upper center') 
        plt.xlim(0,24)
        plt.xticks(np.linspace(0, 24, 7, endpoint=True))
        plt.title('hmF2, foF2 e h\'F para ' + fn[:-4])
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.savefig(directory+'out\\'+fn[:2]+fn[-9:-4]+'_h_fo')
        plt.clf() 
        plt.gcf() 
        plt.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you also put up an image of what you are getting and provide some fake data your your code is runable?  I get the correct result from your code using the master branch.

Comment: this pic is the correct one... if you try to run multiple_yaxis_with_spines.py with matplotlib more recent than 1.1.1 you won't get the red curve correctly

Comment: The `multiple_yaxis_with_spines.py` example runs correctly for me on master. Please provide a copy-paste run-able example to show the problem (http://sscce.org/).